# Pasting string back to column names after removing it with gsub

Tags: r

I need help pasting back a string in the column name after removing it with gsub. I removed it to see how many duplicate samples there are and to keep only the paired (or duplicate samples).

For instance:

```
        A_111_apples_red B_111_apples_red A_11_bananas_yellow B_11_bananas_yellow
Store.A                5                6                   7                    8
Store.B                6                5                   4                    3
Store.C                3                4                   5                    6
```

I used a code such as:

```
sample <- colnames(data)
sample <- gsub("A_|B_", "", sample)
sample <- sample[duplicated(sample)]
```

Now that I know how many duplicate samples there are, and want to keep the duplicate samples, how can I paste "A_" and "B_" back into the column names and create a new data frame with just the duplicate samples (columns)?

Comment: can you include the expected results in your post? Also no need to remove the `A_|B_`

Comment: Please try to indent your code only once in the future and your presentation will look much cleaner. This time I helped you with this and some of your other questions. Cheers!

Comment: Expected results will be a similar matrix as above but with only duplicate samples (independent of the prefix A_/B_). In the example I provided all samples are duplicated however, in the actual matrix, there are some samples that don't have the A_/B_ pair, which need to be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Assuming `"B__"` is a typo and `"B_"` is meant, subset `dat`a with boolean output of `duplicated`. I use different object names to not cause a clash with reserved function names (`sample` and `data`).

```
(dupes <- duplicated(gsub("A_|B_", "", colnames(dat))))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

(dupes <- duplicated(substr(names(dat), 1, 1)))  ## alternatively using `substr()`
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

dat_dupes <- dat[dupes]
dat_dupes
#         B_111_apples_red B_11_bananas_yellow
# Store.A                6                   8
# Store.B                5                   3
# Store.C                4                   6

dat_wo_dupes <- dat[!dupes]
dat_wo_dupes
#         A_111_apples_red A_11_bananas_yellow
# Store.A                5                   7
# Store.B                6                   4
# Store.C                3                   5
```

Or, split the columns into a list like so:

```
dat_lst <- lapply(unique(dupes), \(x) dat[dupes == x])
dat_lst
# [[1]]
# A_111_apples_red B_111_apples_red
# Store.A                5                6
# Store.B                6                5
# Store.C                3                4
# 
# [[2]]
# A_11_bananas_yellow B_11_bananas_yellow
# Store.A                   7                   8
# Store.B                   4                   3
# Store.C                   5                   6
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(A_111_apples_red = c(5L, 6L, 3L), B_111_apples_red = 6:4, 
    A_11_bananas_yellow = c(7L, 4L, 5L), B_11_bananas_yellow = c(8L, 
    3L, 6L)), row.names = c("Store.A", "Store.B", "Store.C"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your solution worked jay.sf. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Update to clarify:

I assume you want to check whether you you have duplicated column names indepdendent from the prefix `A_` `B_`

If I am correct: then `111_apples_red` string is the only one that is duplicated:

So now having `111_apples_red` you want to add again the prefixes:
You can do this by detecting the string `111_apples_red` in the columnnames.
Indirectly you add the prefixes `A_` and `B_` back.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  select(contains(sample))
```

```
        A_111_apples_red B_111_apples_red
Store A                5                6
Store B                6                5
Store C                3                4
```

If `B__11_bananas_yellow` is a typo as stated by jay.sf and should be `B_11_bananas_yellos` then:

```
with the same code:

data %>% 
  select(contains(sample))
```

We get:

```
        A_111_apples_red B_111_apples_red A_11_bananas_yellow B_11_bananas_yellow
Store A                5                6                   7                   8
Store B                6                5                   4                   3
Store C                3                4                   5                   6
```